# Maven build for git committed code

Tags: java, git, maven, gradle, ant

Is there any build tool like maven,gradle support to build only staged/committed code not to include unstaged/untracked file.

Basically while development some scenarios arise in middle I want to check what committed package vs uncommitted one.Though I can achieve two different directory but such flexibility in any build tool will help a lot.

Ex: Consider I have one maven project I modified and committed & pushed the code to GIT Repo.Later I started my further development.When I do build, it builds including all the files but I wanted to know If there is any way I can skip the  unstaged/untracked files in maven pom.xml to build only committed files.Any plugin like that which helps to achieve this or any other build tools.

Comment: Like a [Continuous Integration](https://www.thoughtworks.com/continuous-integration) tool?

Comment: Please clarify your question with a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) comes in handy for this:

> Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the `HEAD` commit.

Answer (score 0):

Something I use and find very convenient is particular Source Code Management plugin for Jenkins, see complete list of similar [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Sourcecodemanagement). In my case I use Git plugin, which provides **Refspec** configuration property. I put there either committed or uncommitted changes' refspec. The build uses source code built until the change pointed in the refspec. Due to my understanding - this is exactly what you need.

P.S. I also build with maven, even though this doesn't matter for this case.